# Could Zabbix agent store measurements what the agent gathers?

Tags: zabbix, zabbix-agent

I'm newbie of Zabbix.

In my project, I'm using Zabbix to know loads of server like CPU usage.
I'm going to investigate loads of poor server with using Zabbix in the future.

Then, the poor server makes me worried about investigation with Zabbix, because loads of the investigation may stop the server. 
So, I found an idea to decrease load of poor server. My idea is  like below.

1. Storing measurements which is collected by zabbix per second in poor server
2. Reporting the summary of measurements per minute

Could my idea be achievable in Zabbix?

Answer (score 0):

In Zabbix, you can make a new `item` that has the key `system.cpu.load[percpu,avg1]` and an update time of 1 minute (See picture).

[image: Zabbix Screenshot of System CPU Load]

This will query the server every minute and take the CPU stats, updating them in Zabbix. If this is your only item, the Zabbix server will only send one request to Zabbix agent every minute, thus satisfying your requirements.

Comment: Thank you for giving me advice! In the end,  I couldn't configure Zabbix to make the agent store measurement what it collects per second to report the measurement to me per minute?